# console.log directly of property of object shows another result than the same property while console the object itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When console.log the state.recipe object itself it shows the property of showings is 8, but when console.log state.recipe.servings separately it shows 4. No 4 exist, I added all HTML in JS without any 4. ctrl+shift+r or ctrl+f5 doesn't help. What can it be. Thank you. [image: here]

[image: here]

Comment: Deleted my previous comment; please don't post pictures of code, it makes us assume things like `state` is from an actual `useState` [why images of code are bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Too hard to see what might cause this. Could be stale state, shallow copy of objects, or something else. [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)